# on PHP, how can i use a variable that is inside an IF statement, and use it outside of the IF statement

Tags: php, search

I have a problem regarding my variable. I want to get my declared variable inside the IF statement and use it on the outside of my code. anyone can help me? this is my code that gives me error.

```
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
     $_SESSION['find']=$_POST['search'];
     $search=$_SESSION['find'];
     echo "<b class='text-info'><u>".ucwords($search)."</u></b></b>";  
}

$query=mysql_query("select * from tbl_studentpersonalinfo where firstName LIKE '%".$search."%' OR lastName LIKE '%".$search."%'");
$total=mysql_num_rows($query);
```

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: mysql is deprecated use mysqli or PDO instead! -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Why do you have two closing `</b>` tags?

Comment: I dont think right now you will get error if your IF statement is working fine. Even if you are getting it, then just add $search=""; before your if condition.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_SESSION['find']);` output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$thevariableiwantoutside="";

  if(isset($_POST['search']))
  {
       $thevariableiwantoutside="what i want it to be";
       $_SESSION['find']=$_POST['search'];
       $search=$_SESSION['find'];
       echo "<b class='text-info'><u>".ucwords($search)."</u></b></b>";  
  }

$query=mysql_query("select * from tbl_studentpersonalinfo where firstName LIKE '%".$search."%' OR lastName LIKE '%".$search."%'");
$total=mysql_num_rows($query);

echo $thevariableiwantoutside;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a variable outside a `if`, if the variable is defined inside the `if`.
This is the variables scope.

Solution :

- Create the variable outside before the `if`
- Fill it inside the `if`
- Use it outside the `if`

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you use $_POST['search'] itself?

```
 if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
     $_SESSION['find']=$_POST['search'];
     $search=$_SESSION['find'];
     echo "<b class='text-info'><u>".ucwords($search)."</u></b></b>";  
}

$query=mysql_query("select * from tbl_studentpersonalinfo where firstName LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%' OR lastName LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%'");
$total=mysql_num_rows($query);
```

Answer (score 1):

just set:

```
$search=NULL;
```

before if statement, then you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think right now you will get error if your IF statement is working fine. Even if you are getting it, then just add `$search="";` before your if condition.